# Reduce cyclomatic complexity of a function

Tags: typescript, cyclomatic-complexity

This function checks if the cell of a scrabble board is a double letter bonus. It has a 23 cyclomatic complexity which is  higher than the threshold of 20. I don't know how to do it another way, I think that this is the only way to do it.
Here is my function :

```
checkDoubleLetterCell(row: number, column: number): boolean
{
    if((row === middle- 1 || row === middle + 1)
    && (column === middle - 1 || column === middle + 1)
    || (row === 0 || row == SCRABBLE_SIZE - 1 || row === middle) 
    && (column === middle + Math.round(middle/2) || column === middle - Math.round(middle/2))
    || (column === 0 || column === SCRABBLE_SIZE - 1 || column === middle)
    && (row === middle + Math.round(middle/2) || row === middle - Math.round(middle/2))
    || (column === middle + 1 || column === middle - 1)
    && (row === middle + Math.round(middle/2) + 1 || row === middle - Math.round(middle/2) - 1)
    || (row === middle + 1 || row === middle - 1)
    && (column === middle + Math.round(middle/2) + 1 || column === middle - Math.round(middle/2) - 1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Extract each operand of your long `or` condition into its own function. Or just ignore the warning if you consider the code to be readable enough.

Comment: Consider migrating this question to codereview.stackexchange.com - there are always other ways to write code, but it looks like the major issues here is communication and ability to reason about the code by reading it - which would be off topic on stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to represent static knowledge in data instead of in procedural code. If the knowledge about the location of the double letter squares is represented in a statically initialized data structure, say a boolean matrix dblScore of the right dimensions, then your code reduces to:

```
checkDoubleLetterCell(row: number, column: number): boolean
{
    return dblScore[row,column]; 
}
```

Excess complexity is often the side-effect of choosing an ill-fitting representation. A general rule: static knowledge should be represented in data, not in procedural logic.